# requestAction in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I've integrated GeoIP into my CakePHP. Now I have to call it from my view-file. I made in my controller such function:

```
function getCountry($ip)
{
    $this->GeoIP->countryName($ip);
}
```

`GeoIP` is a included component.

When I wrote in my view globally something like this:
`$this->GeoIP->countryName('8.8.8.8')` it works well, but, as I remember, this is wrong for MCV architecture. So the right way is to call `requestAction` for my controller.

Here I have 2 problems: I have to do this in php function which is located in view-file:

```
// MyView.php:
<?php
   function Foo()
   {
      $this->GeoIP->countryName(...);
   }
?>
```

First mistake is that `$this` isn't available inside the function, the second one is how to call `getCountry` from my component and pass need ip address into `$ip`?

I've tried:

```
echo $this->requestAction('Monitoring/getCountry/8.8.8.8');
```

`Monitoring` is a controller name.

But this returns nothing without any errors. What's the right way and how to call this in function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

Layout -> **View/Layouts/default.ctp** *(works on any other view/element or block)*

```
<h1>My Website</h1>
<?php echo $this->element('GeoIP') ?>
```

Element -> **View/Elements/GeoIP.ctp** *(use an element so you can cache it and don't request the controller every time)*

```
<?php
$country = $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'Monitoring', 'action' => 'ipToCountry'));

echo "You're from {$country}?";
?>
```

Controller -> **Controller/MonitoringController.php**

```
public function ipToCountry() {
    // Only accessible via requestAction()
    if (empty($this->request->params['requested']))
        throw new ForbiddenException();

    return $this->GeoIP->countryName('8.8.8.8');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the basic principles in MVC is that you must not use logic in your view files (except some conditions). In your controller you must set the value in the view and use it there.

I you absolutely need to call your  method after all the logic in the controller, you can use the beforeRender() method in your controller and it will be called right before rendering. You can set your value from there.

I don't see why you'd like to call a controller function in the view, unless you have business logic in there. That should be moved in the controller.

Hope I helped!